# Selenium Wait for user to click on alert dialog box in python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, click, alert, webdriverwait

I have created a dialog box in browser (this Happens when an error occurs in user input details). What I need is to wait until the user clicks on the dialog box before preceding with automatic execution (only for testing). Here is what I have

```
# driver is a chrome web driver
driver.execute_script("alert('qwer');")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)    
element = wait.until(EC.alert_is_present())
```

I tried to search online but only got an answer when a user clicks on a button inside a webpage but not on a generated dialog box. How to do it (if possible)?

Comment: Hey There, are you looking for a way to wait until the alert box is visible, or would a way to interact with the alert box be useful at all?

Comment: You could try to use the builtin `time` module. I forgot which function you have to call, but there is one that waits for an action, and then executes the following code.

Comment: Also out of curiosity - What is the variable "EC" in your posted code? Thanks :)

Comment: I just want to wait until the user clicks on the dialog box. Similar to alert,accept() but done by the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from time import sleep
while EC.alert_is_present()(driver):
    sleep(30)
```

If you simply want to alert the user then use pymsgbox or Telegram API to send him a message,

```
from pymsgbox import alert
alert("Hey User")
```

Comment: Here you are just waiting for a an amount of time. So, it is not possible check for user click?!

Comment: See the while condition

Comment: Well, it keeps running forever even after I click on ok.

Comment: Even after 30s? Reduce the seconds.

Comment: Yes, I tried to reduce the seconds even to 5 but not working

Comment: If the alert is closed and I try driver.switch_to.alert I get no NoAlertPresentException.  So, I think I will catch the exception exit loop when it happens. Thank you.